Removing blank spaces and lines is not working for me
I am unable to remove the tab spaces from the web data, which I want to enter into an excel sheet.
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url='https://www.screener.in/screens/41109/all-stocks/?limit=100&page=1'

response = r.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table=soup.find_all('table')
table_len=soup.find_all(len('table'))

scrnr_table=soup.find_all('th')
header_tags=[header.text.strip('\n') for header in scrnr_table]
data_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
row_values = [dr.text.strip() for dr in data_rows]


for header in header_tags:
        h_values=header.strip('\n')
        print(header)

Answer :
  S.No.
Name
                    CMP
                    Rs.
                    P/E
                    
                    Mar Cap
                    Rs.Cr.
                    Div Yld
                    %
                    NP Qtr
                    Rs.Cr.
                    Qtr Profit Var
                    %
                    Sales Qtr
                    Rs.Cr.
                    Qtr Sales Var
                    %
                    ROCE
                    %
S.No.
Name
                    CMP
                    Rs.
                    P/E
                    
                    Mar Cap
                    Rs.Cr.
                    Div Yld
                    %
                    NP Qtr
                    Rs.Cr.
                    Qtr Profit Var
                    %
                    Sales Qtr
                    Rs.Cr.
                    Qtr Sales Var
                    %
                    ROCE
                    %

The spaces that are populating doesn't seems to be affected by the str.strip('\n') or str.strip('\t') method.
Kindly help me out on this.

If you simply use .strip() it will remove leading and trailing whitespace. In either case, you may want to use a regular expression to remove any non-printable text.

maybe header.get_text('\n', strip=True)? Adding a sample of the html would be nicer that downloading the url

Try printing the result of the strip instead  print(h_values)

Include the part of the code where you attempt to remove spaces and lines. This will help diagnose the issue.

Use bs4.BeautifulSoup.get_text method to control the symbol of separator and the strip flag. Here how to edit the corresponding line:
header_tags = [header.get_text('\n', strip=True) for header in scrnr_table]

Here the first few results of the output
S.No.
Name
CMP
Rs.
P/E
Mar Cap
Rs.Cr.
Div Yld
%
NP Qtr
#[...]

Notice that no empty line is present.
